# Suggestions for creating a Unique ID when doing a UNION of more tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, uniqueidentifier

I have a view made like this

```
CREATE VIEW PEOPLE

AS

SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeName FROM Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT FriendId, FriendName From Friends
```

now I need to add unique ID for the view, because of course i can have a `CustomerId = 15` and an `EmployeeID = 15`

So the trick I am doing is the following

```
SELECT
  CAST('1' + CAST(CustomerId AS VARCHAR(30)) AS INT) as UniqueCustomerId,
 CustomerId, CustomerName FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT
  CAST('2' + CAST(EmployeeId AS VARCHAR(30)) AS INT) as UniqueEmployeeId,
 EmployeeId, EmployeeName FROM Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT
  CAST('3' + CAST(FriendId AS VARCHAR(30)) AS INT) as UniqueFriendId, 
FriendId, FriendName From Friends
```

Anyway this casting to `varchar(30)` and back to `int` is an overhead since I have many records.

Could you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Does it need to be a single column unique identifier? It would seem that keeping the person type in a separate column would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got to have a single id, just do math:

```
SELECT  1000000 + CustomerID AS UniqueCustomerId
      , CustomerId
      , CustomerName
FROM    Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT  2000000 + EmployeeId AS UniqueEmployeeId
      , EmployeeId
      , EmployeeName
FROM    Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT  3000000 + FriendId AS UniqueFriendId
      , FriendId
      , FriendName
FROM    Friends
```

Comment: in the night after asking this question i give the same answer during my sleep!

Comment: what happens after 10... ive got some id's that are 11000000 .. if i increase a couple of 0.. doesnt seems to like it.

Comment: If you increase the length of the integer too far you may have exceeded the maximum value of an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach as it can still use indexes on the CustomerID, EmployeeID, and FriendID

```
SELECT 1 [PersonType],CustomerId [PersonId], CustomerName [PersonName] FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, EmployeeId, EmployeeName FROM Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, FriendId, FriendName From Friends
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean and well readable, I use this in Postgres.

```
select CAST(row_number() OVER () AS bigint) AS id,
       *
from (
         select mtm.id     as mkt_tech_map_id,
                'vesivagu' as type,
                mv.geom,
                ''         as label
         from mkt_tech_map mtm
                  left join mkt_vesivagu mv on mtm.id = mv.mkt_tech_map_id

         union

         select mtm.id       as mkt_tech_map_id,
                'kraavisete' as type,
                mk.geom,
                ''           as label
         from mkt_tech_map mtm
                  left join mkt_kraavisete mk on mtm.id = mk.mkt_tech_map_id

         
     ) as q
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
CREATE VIEW PEOPLE AS  
SELECT CustomerId, null as EmployeeId, null as FriendId, CustomerName FROM Customers 
UNION ALL 
SELECT null, EmployeeId, null, EmployeeName FROM Employees 
UNION ALL 
SELECT null, null, FriendId, FriendName From Friends
```